# How can I get data from a .json file in Handlebars.js without using {{#each}} or {{#if}}?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I've been using `{{#each}}` and `{{#if}}` in handlebars.js to grab data from JSON files. But I need a way to get the data without any conditions. I have no need for an `{{#if}}` statement and there's only one set of data so I don't need `{{#each}}` either. Is there a way to do this? `{{#each}}` works but I don't want to be using that if there's a simpler method to get a single block of data.

I should note that I'm using Grunt with Handlebars and that my document calls from more than just one JSON file.

Here is my code.

```
  {{data.PaymentMethod}}
  <table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>Payment Method</div>
      <div>Card Number: {{CardNumber}}</div>
      <div>Card Colder: {{CardHolder}}</div>
      <div><a href="{{Link}}">Tracking</a></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

And this is my JSON file (`data.json`).

```
{
"PaymentMethod": [
        {
            "CardNumber": "****",
            "CardHolder": "John Doe",
            "Link": "http://www.test.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: How do you call your template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div>Card Number: {{data.PaymentMethod.0.CardNumber}}</div>
<div>Card Colder: {{data.PaymentMethod.[0].CardHolder}}</div>
```

You should be able to access it like so. Because `data.PaymentMethod` is an array you have to access the first object in that array.

Comment: Must be missing something as this did not work for me. I'm running Grunt and I got this in my cmd window: `Expecting 'ID', got 'INVALID'`

Comment: ah i was missing out on the `.` before the array value. the brackets are optional in this case but not if you are using the `with` helper

Comment: The new code no longer throws any errors, but it's not pulling any data in either. :( I've confirmed the filename is right as is the contents of the JSON file. The `with` helper works for me, but not this. I imagine if I could get your answer to work then that would be ideal because it's less code.

Comment: does the `with` helper work with or without the `data` part? If it works without have you tried removing the `data.` from the above code?

Comment: `{{#with data.PaymentMethod.[0]}}` doesn't work but `{{#with PaymentMethod.[0]}}` does.

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing differently, but this has started working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`#with`](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html#with) helper to step into the array:

```
{{#with PaymentMethod.[0]}}
    <div>Payment Method</div>
    <div>Card Number: {{CardNumber}}</div>
    <div>Card Colder: {{CardHolder}}</div>
    <div><a href="{{Link}}">Tracking</a></div>
{{/with}}
```

Comment: I've got multiple JSON files. I noticed your code doesn't specifiy the data.json file. Should there be something in there to make sure it doesn't pull from the wrong JSON file if the `PaymentMethod` exists elsewhere?

Comment: @jimmykup I'm not sure what you mean. What does the data file have to do with the template?

Comment: What I mean is that somewhere else in my document I might pull from `data2.json`. `data.json` and `data2.json` might both have `PaymentMethod` in them (with different data). Your code doesn't explicitly specify to look inside data.json. Would it be best/possible to do that?